# React: Mapping object returning nothing

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, npm

I just started to use React and I'm trying to import some dummy XML for looping through. I found some people use map() but I'm having issues with it where it returns nothing or gives an error.

The XML can be found here https://web-designer.ninja/jsfiddle/guestlist.xml

Here is my component js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import XMLMapping from 'xml-mapping';
import axios from 'axios';

class Guests extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        guests: []
    };
 }

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eMatsiyana/e315b60a2930bb79e869b37a6ddf8ef1/raw/10c057b39a4dccbe39d3151be78c686dcd1101aa/guestlist.xml')
  .then(res => {
    const xml = XMLMapping.load(res.data, { comments: false, arrays: [
      '/dataset/record'
     ] });
    var guests  = XMLMapping.tojson(xml, {indent: true});
    //console.log(xml);
    this.setState({ guests });
  //return guests;
  });
}
  render() {
    function mapObject(object, callback) {
      return Object.keys(object).map(function (key) {
        return callback(key, object[key]);
      });
    }
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="container">
                <section className="section">
                    <h1 className="title">Guests attending Event A</h1>               
                    <div className="columns">
                    {mapObject(this.state.guests, function (key, value) {
                      //return <div>Value: {value.record}</div>;
                      return <div key={key}>id: {value.record.first_name}</div>;
                    })}
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Guests;
```

if I uncomment this line: `return <div>Value: {value.record}</div>;`

It throws this error in the browser: (guessing because it's a object but I can't seem to get value.record.first_name or value.record[first_name])

[image]

Any help or guidance will be appreciated!

**Update**

Managed to get it to work with this:

```
{mapObject(this.state.guests, function (key, value) {
    return <div>
        {value.record.map((item,index) => {
              console.log(item.first_name.$t)
              return item.first_name.$t;
        })}
          </div>
 })}
```

Need to get used to how react handles returns. But if someone can explain why this will work, I'd definitely accept the answer.

Comment: i think its empty because there are no guests records returned

Comment: Some issues off the bat: never `setState(...);` in the render function as it will cause an INFINITE render.

Comment: In replace of setState, what should I use @fungusanthrax ?

Comment: Please put the fetcher of data in **componentDidMount** and THEN it should work. guests is never defined because you are fetching the data, setting it in state, causing a rerender, which fetches the data, causing a rerender, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @fungusanthrax it's still not returning anything using `return <div key={key}>id: {value.record.first_name}`

Comment: What does a simple `console.log(this.state.guests)` inside your render print? I suggest going from there.

Comment: I think it's cause you are setting guests wrong in the state. Try this: `setState({guests: guests});` The difference is you are specifying WHAT state property to update. Also, shouldn't the fetched data, guests, be an object? You're declaring it to be an empty array in **getInitialState**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fungusanthrax. `return <div>Value: {value.record}</div>` is returning a object. I didn't follow the json data structure returned (very clumsy). I basically followed the structure and got it to work with `value.record[0].first_name.$t`. But is there anyway of getting a counter to work with `record[0]`?